# MatchIt reusing control units multiple times in a panel data setting

Tags: r, propensity-scores, matching

I have a panel data with treated and non-treated firm year-quarters, and I would like to do  propensity score matching to generate a treated/control firm subsample. The matching needs to be 1 to 1 and matched pair needs to be in the same year.

The code I'm using is :

```
m.out <- matchit(treated ~ covariates +I(year), 
                  data = sample,
                  method = "nearest", 
                  distance = "glm", 
                  link = "logit",
                  exact="year",
                  ratio=1,
                  replace = FALSE)
```

Which works fine, but it matches the same firm multiple times as controls. Not the same control firm-year-quarter, but the same firm. Is there any way to only use the same control firm once?

Comment: Yes, use the `unit.id` argument, which was designed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Noah! Worked perfectly